# generate elements dynamically based on json file in bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with BootstrapVue (Bootstrap 4.6 and VueJS 2) !

I want to create elements (input fields, dropdowns, checkboxes, etc.) dynamically based on a json file which is looking like that:

```
[
    {
        "unique_number": "1111",
        "key": "key1",
        "label": "Input 1",
        "input": "text",
        "value": ""
    },

    {
        "unique_number": "2222",
        "key": "key2",
        "label": "Input 2",
        "input": "text",
        "value": ""
    },

    {
        "unique_number": "3333",
        "key": "key3",
        "label": "Input 3",
        "input": "number",
        "value": ""
    }
]
```

So at the end there should be 3 input fields with 3 labels (Input 1, Input 2, Input 3)..

But I actually could not find something online to work with - so it would be very helpful if someone can help me out in this..

Comment: You need to [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?retiredLocale=en) element, then use [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement?retiredLocale=en)

Answer (score 1):

You need to map through the data, and return a component that takes the data from .map

```
const array = [
    {
        "unique_number": "1111",
        "key": "key1",
        "label": "Input 1",
        "input": "text",
        "value": ""
    },

    {
        "unique_number": "2222",
        "key": "key2",
        "label": "Input 2",
        "input": "text",
        "value": ""
    },

    {
        "unique_number": "3333",
        "key": "key3",
        "label": "Input 3",
        "input": "number",
        "value": ""
    }
]
```

I don't use Vue, but I'm sure its similar to how its done in React:

```
array.map((element,key) => {
   return (
    <div key={key}>
      <SomeComponent prop={element.prop}/>
   </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Right track, however Vue utilizes [directives](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html). In this case it would be `<div v-for="element in array"> <input :label="element.unique_number" /> </div>`

Comment: Thanks for answering - the problem is that I'm importing my json file to a component..  so I could not write "const array = [{}]" - do you have any solution for this?

Comment: `const array = require('./<nameOfFile>.json')
console.log(array)` and see if that prints out your list, you can also try using ES6 module support and use `import` instead of `require`